# fetch в статусе возвращает 0

Tags: javascript, fetch

Почему fetch возвращает 0. Задача: обработать статус ответа от сервера.

```
function beginAuth(data) {
        fetch("/login", {
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
            redirect: "manual"
        }).then(response => {
            alert(response.status);
            // window.location.replace("/index")
        });
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю это ваш сервер отвечает таким статусом

Comment: Посмотрите также на  alert(response.statusText); alert(response.ok);

Comment: вряд-ли nginx ответит статусом - 0 при редиректе

Comment: statusText ничего не возвращает, а response.ok возвращает false

Comment: Думаю есть повод посмотреть на сервер. И посмотреть на обработку посылаемого запроса